# First column as link in SharePoint view

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a custom list with below two columns.

```
Col 1
Col 2
```

In the default view, "Title" column is the link to view item. I have removed this column from this view but I am not able to set Col 1 as my link to view item. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this [article](http://kamilmka.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/enable-context-menu-in-a-custom-column/).  This should help you change the linked item in the SharePoint list.

Comment: Could you please help me with one more query of mine? I want to add edit icon column in my view.

Comment: Try this [article](http://www.manageprojectsonsharepoint.com/archive/2011/02/14/choice-indicator-icon-columns.aspx).